# anychart. Переделал код по ответу из тп

Tags: javascript

Был у меня код - он особо не работал. Написал им в тп(потому что, мне казалось, что должно работать) и они дали ответ -

**1) if you want to go with streaming on basic charts you need to study how mapping and data sets work: https://playground.anychart.com/kOeAbxwO**

**In this sample we commented the fetch part - you have to figure it out yourself, but if it works properly -  everything else should work too.**

**Data sets and mapping info:
https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Data_Sets
https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Data_Manipulation**

**2) if you want to go with AnyStock - it is pretty similar but different:
https://playground.anychart.com/kOeAbxwO/3**

**Stock charts work with time based table: https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Table_Data_Model**

Открыв первую ссылку и почитав, что пишут в остальных, я понял, что нужно слегка переделать код (на такой, какой он впервой ссылке). Я переделал и вот, что получилось -

```
async function requestAndTreatment() {
        const response = await fetch(requestURL);
        const res = await response.json();
        console.log(res);
        //Получаем дату с апишки
        let time = res.timestamp;
        let date = new Date(time);
        //Получаем цены с апишки
        let open = res.data[0].open;
        let high = res.data[0].high;
        let low = res.data[0].low;
        let close = res.data[0].close;

        //Переводим миллисекунды в год, месяц...

        let year = date.getFullYear();
        let month = date.getMonth();
        let day = date.getDate();
        let hours = date.getHours();
        let minutes = date.getMinutes();
        //Добавляем "0" перед цифрой, если в месяце цифра, а не число
        if (month < 10) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        //заполняет массив информацией.
        data.addData([[Date.UTC(year, month, day), open, high, low, close]]);
        console.log(data);
      }

      let data = anychart.data.table(0);

      anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
      // create a chart
      chart = anychart.stock();
 
      mapping = data.mapAs({open: 1, high: 2, low: 3, close: 4});
      // create a japanese candlestick series and set the data
      var series = chart.plot(0).candlestick(mapping);
 
      // set container id
      chart.container("container");
 
      // initiate drawing the chart
      chart.draw();
 
      setInterval(requestAndTreatment, 1000);
})
```

Но консоль ругается, говорит - **anychart.data.table is not a function**

Скорее всего, я как-то не верно переписал код, но, что именно не так, не могу понять. Помогите пожалуйста, понять, в чем ошибка.

Comment: в консоль пробовали вывести anychart.data ? может там так надо: anychart.data.table[0]

Comment: @Konst Результать консоль лога - большой объект и ниже сразу выводится **undefiend**, попробовал заменить на **[0]** - **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

Comment: посмотрите их пример https://playground.anychart.com/api/data/_samples/anychart.data.Table.createComputer там используют var dataTable = anychart.data.table();